# How to check if a point is inside a non-axis-aligned rectangle?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, transformation

I have a point $P$ defined by ($x_1$, $y_1$) and a rectangle $R$ that is defined by a point $M$ ($x_2$, $y_2$), height($h$) and width($w$).

I know I can easily find out if the point is inside it if it's axis-aligned, by calculating minimum and maximum $x$ and $x$ of $R$ and comparing them with the $x$ and $y$ of $P$, however it doesn't work when $R$ is rotated.

Is there a way to somehow transform $P$ without transforming $R$, so I can then compare them as if $R$ is axis-aligned?

I saw a lot of methods where they calculate the points of the rectangle and then apply matrix transformations to them, but that's very computationally expensive.
Is there a "minimally invasive" method, like transforming only $P$ to "fit" the rotation of $R$?

I tried using the transformation matrix $M_1$ that represents the position, rotation, scale of $R$ and inverting it:

$M_2 = Inverse(M_1)$

And I transform $P$ with $M_2$, however it doesn't check out. It still only works when $R$ is axis-aligned, not when it rotates.

Is there any other way?

EDIT:

The rectangle $R$ can also be defined by a 4x4 matrix(the $M_1$ matrix)
It's the transform matrix that determines the position, rotation and scale of the rectangle, so $M$ is basically the position component of the matrix $M_1$.
I'm transforming $P$ by the inverse of $M_1$ and then trying to treat $R$ as just axis aligned, but it's not working.

EDIT2:
Here's a concrete example(some of the variables have changed, I had missed to add something):

I have a point $P$ in 3D space and a rectangle $R$ that has its position, scale and rotation represented by the transform matrix $M_1$.

I need to transform $P$ into the "frame" of $R$, so I can then treat them as a 2D point and a 2D axis-aligned rectagle on a 2D plane and perform a simple test to see if the $P$ is inside $R$.
So far I've been transforming $P$ by $M_1^-1$, which seems to only work when $R$ is rotated on the $z$ axis(if $M_1$ has a rotation on the $z$ axis). If $R$ is however tilted(rotated on the $x$ or $y$ axis), for some reason the tests of $P$ being in $R$ don't work.

EDIT3:

$R$ center position $x y z$: $(0, 0, 0)$
$R$ rotation angles on the $x y z$ axes: $(30, 30, 30)$
$R$ transformation matrix:

$M_1$
$$
 \begin{matrix}
 0.875 & 0.433 & -0.216 & 0 \\
 -0.216 & 0.75 & 0.625 & 0 \\
 0.433 & -0.5 & 0.75 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{matrix}
$$

$R$ inverse transform (approximated):

$M_1^{-1}$
$$
 \begin{matrix}
 0.875 & -0.216 & 0.433 & 0 \\
 0.433 & 0.75 & -0.5 & 0 \\
 -0.216 & 0.625 & 0.75 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{matrix}
$$

point $P$ $xyz$ before transformation: $(0.81, -1.61, 0)$

point $P$ $xyz$ after transformation: $(0.014, -1.38, 1.16)$

I need point $P$ to be as if it's aligned with the transform of $R$, as if it's only 2D and to be able to use the simple 2D algorithm to check if $P$ is inside $R$

[image]

Comment: $M$, $h$ and $w$ don't define a rectangle until you provide information about how it's tilted. If you tell us the form that information takes (an angle? another vertex?) we can suggest an algorithm for answering your questions.

Comment: @EthanBolker ah yes I edited it, thanks.

Comment: It’s still not completely clear to me how $M_1$ represents the rectangle. Does it transform the unit square into the rectangle that you’re trying to test against?

Comment: @amd $M_1$ is the transformation matrix of the rectangle(position, rotation, scale)

Comment: Yes, but what rectangle does the example you’ve added actually represent? $M_1$ is a simple rotation with no translation or scaling, so is it meant to describe a rotated unit square?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work, but assuming that the matrix $M_1$ means what it usually means, your rectangle consists of all point $Mu$, where $u = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$, with $0 \le x \le 1$.

In that case, letting $M_2 = M_1^{-1}$, you can say that a point $P$ (at least a point $P$ that's in the right plane!) is in the rectangle if

$$v = M_2 P$$
is a point *in the unit square* (not just in *any* axis-aligned rectangle).

If you're really sure this doesn't work for you, tell us an explicit example of the matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ and a point $P$, and perhaps we can help you out.

Comment: $Mu$ is a matrix row?

Comment: Ok I found the issue, apparently it was also rotated by the x and y axis, as a form of scaling(it's viewed by an orthographic camera from the top, so it looks 2D). So this is actually the big problem. But wouldn't multiplying by $M_1$ just rotate the point too over the square, so it makes no difference? Or am I misisng something/

Comment: You missed my last sentence: please give a concrete example of a problem, because I can't actually understand your comment above, but I think I'll get it when I see an actual example.

Comment: Ok I added the entire specific problem on the last edit, sorry for missing those things before.

Comment: I'm not sure if maybe calculating some kind of plane normal from the rectangle and then projecting the point on the rectangle is going to work, is that a viable option?

Comment: Numbers! Give an actual example of a matrix, please.

Comment: Ok I edited and added a specific example with numbers, I'll also try to add an example drawing

Comment: I added a picture for clarity